# Connect output pin from MCP23017 to Input pin on another MCP23017 (2 independent arduinos)

Tags: c++, arduino, esp32

Im struggling with the following scenario: I have 2 ESP32 boards (Dev Kit 1) and each ESP32 has 1 MCP23017 I2C module connected to it. So my goal is to use all 16 pins on MCP 1 as Output and all other 16 pins on second MCP as inputs and be able to "READ" these values (HIGH OR LOW) I Already setup connection using common ground on both ESP and wiring SDA SCL accordingly. I Already tested using input and output on same MCP unit and works fine (displays on COM port a seral.println message) but when I want to do the same thing but connecting from MCP1 output pin 1 to MCP2 input pin 1, nothing happens on the COM port, but when I unplug the jumper wire (which I use to connect input pin to output pin on the protoboard) then it does detect the voltage change and displays the message. Any idea whats going on here? Why I cant bridge from 1 MCP output to another MCP input and be able to detect this on COM port? Im using following code:

```
#include "Adafruit_MCP23017.h"

Adafruit_MCP23017 mcp1;    // Instantiate mcp module object 1, (MCP001)
int dly = 250;            // 1/4 second delay 

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); 
  Serial.begin(19200);
  Serial.println("MCP module 1 Ready");

  mcp1.begin();            // "Start" the mcp object

 mcp1.pinMode(0, OUTPUT); //set pin "0" on MCP1 as output
 mcp1.pinMode(1, INPUT); //set next pin "1" on MCP1 as input
  
}

void loop() {

    mcp1.digitalWrite(0, HIGH);        // Set pin HIGH (on)

    if (mcp1.digitalRead (1 == HIGH)) {
      Serial.println("Continuity Detected at Pin 1 ");
      }
     mcp1.digitalWrite(0, LOW);         // Set pin LOW (off)   
     delay(dly);                       // On for 1/4 second
    
}
```

Comment: You should really test the return value of the call to `begin()` to make sure the library was able to find the sensor. Also, the [current version of the library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-MCP23017-Arduino-Library/tree/master/src) doesn't appear to have a file named `Adafruit_MCP23017.h` - are you sure you're using the most recent version (2.1.0)?

Comment: Yes, you are correct, Im using an older version as newest version (2.1.0) Im not able to make it work. So I used version version 1.0. However, by using this older version, Im able to make it work with no problems as I mention when testing output pin and input pin on same MCP. Problem comes when connection from output pin from one MCP to the input pin on second MCP which is connected on another ESP32. What is weird is that when I connect the jumper wire, COM port shows nothing, but, when I remove the jumper wire, the COM port starts to show the message of the continuity detected. Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps figuring out why the newest version - which works - doesn’t work for you would shed light on the problem you’re having.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by just removing or commenting out the line 27 (mcp1.digitalWrite(0, LOW);) Now works the way I want. Thanks @romkey for your time and help.